# Recover a deleted file using undelete() in C

Tags: c, macos, undelete

I'm just trying to recover a file in C on an HFS+ formatted Volumn. According to

```
man undelete
```

> **NAME**
>        undelete -- attempt to recover a deleted file
>
> **LIBRARY**
>        Standard C Library (libc, -lc)
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>        #include
>
> ```
>  int
>  undelete(const char *path);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `undelete()` system call attempts to recover the deleted file named
>   by path.  Currently, this works only when the named object is a
>   whiteout in a union file system.  The system call removes the whiteout
>   causing any objects in a lower layer of the union stack to become
>   visible once more.
>
> Eventually, the `undelete()` functionality may be expanded to other file
>   systems able to recover deleted files such as the log-structured file
>   system.
>
> **RETURN VALUES**
>
> The `undelete()` function returns the value 0 if successful; otherwise
>   the value -1 is returned and the global variable `errno` is set to
>   indicate the error.

so the Program is simple:

The current directory (pwd) is /Users/Leo/Desktop/ and I'm on a Mac 10.7.2 with HFS+ Filesystem.

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    char a="/Users/Leo/Desktop/test/a.out";//I delete a.out using rm for testing
    const char* pa=&a;
    return undelete(pa);
}
```

But when I run the program, I got shell returned 255.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: the man page tells you that undelete sets errno.  So call perror to see what the error is.

Comment: Note the documentation says "Currently, this works only when the named object is a whiteout in a union file system.". This is a fairly exotic configuration to have, so this probably isn't the case for you.

Comment: `char a="/Users/Leo/Desktop/test/a.out";` <- invalid char value. You're also using the wrong type. String literals must be either a pointer to const chars (`const char *a = "...";`), or an array of const chars (`const char a[] = "...";`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

undelete is failing.  To find out why, check errno.  For example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    char *path = argc > 1 ? argv[ 1 ] : "a.out";

    if( undelete(path))
        perror( path );
    return 0;
}
```

Although it appears your problem is that you have a char instead of a char pointer.
You should have gotten a compiler warning.

Comment: I tried your code and the errno says
        /Users/Leo/Desktop/test/test: No such file or directory. Actually I created  and removed file "test" for testing

Comment: Read http://lwn.net/Articles/325369/.  You need a directory entry for undelete to work.  Simply using rm on the path will certainly not work if your filesystem is not a union file system.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check the return value and evaluate it. If it is -1 then print an error message, for example with `perror` or by formatting an error message and using `strerror(errno)`.

But you've also got a major bug before you even attempt to call `undelete`:

```
char a="/Users/Leo/Desktop/test/a.out";
const char* pa=&a;
```

This will first assign a value (the pointer to your string) to a `char`, a single byte value. The compiler even warns about that with *warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast.* In my case, `a` then had the value `D`/0x44, but it could have been anything. You then store the pointer to that single byte in `pa`. What you want instead is:

```
const char* pa="/Users/Leo/Desktop/test/a.out";
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it. But the program still don't work after I correct such dumb mistake. errno display /Users/Leo/Desktop/test/test: No such file or directory. Actually I created and removed file "test" for testing. Any further information? thanks

Comment: The man page says: *Currently, this works only when the named object is a whiteout in a union file system.* This means it'll only work with a union mount (see for example [this article](http://aplawrence.com/foo-mac/union-mounts.html) on how to set one up). It will not work on your usual HFS+ mount points.